# Is the return type of a function a type of the function?

Tags: typescript

Problem :

1. Regular function

Is the type of this function - "void" ? (so in the case of a regular function - regular function type = return type of the regular function)
Or is type of this function just - "Function" ?

```
function regularFunction(): void {}
```

2. Named function

Is the type of this function - "() => void" ? (so in the case of a named function - named function type = whatever this function holds within itself)
Or is type of this function just - "void" ? Or maybe - "Function" ?

```
const namedFunction = function (): void {};
```

P.S : I'm not trolling, that's a serious question ... I'm so confused about types of different functions

I tried to seek for an answer on various resourses but they still don't answer my question

Comment: Function types consist of both the argument type *and* the return type. `void` alone is a type, but not a function type. (I'm refraining from answering because I don't know TypeScript well enough to provide a precise answer.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The type of a function is usually referred to as its [signature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_signature) and it includes both the types of the inputs (argument types) and the type of the output (return type). The type of both of your functions is `() => void`, it doesn't matter whether the function is named or anonymous.

In Typescript there exists an interface called `Function`, and all functions implement it, but it is not the type of a *specific* function and generally it is not used very often as it's not terribly useful. Even in generic constraints the preferred alternative is like so

```
function foo<T extends (...args: any) => any>(f: T): whatever
```

Here `T` is guaranteed to be a function.